# Regular Expression in str_detect?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I have colnames like `c1c5, c5c1, c4c3 ...`

And I want to retrieve all colnames that starts or ends with `c4` and `c5`.

I have tried using the following:

```
str_detect(colnames(df), "c5c\\d+")

str_detect(colnames(df), "c4c\\d+")

str_detect(colnames(df), "c\\d+c4")

str_detect(colnames(df), "c\\d+c5")
```

Is there any way to combine it to one expression? Please advise.

Comment: `str_detect(colnames(df), "^c[54]|c[54]$")` / `grep("^c[45]|c[45]$", colnames(df))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for! Please share as an answer and so I will be able to accept it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks a lot for another option, I think regex is simpler and faster. Correct me if you think that I am wrong.

Comment: @steves `grep` also uses regex. It's just a function from base R

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know I meant the solution provided by Wiktor.

Comment: Wiktor edited his comment after I've already posted mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
str_detect(colnames(df), "^c[54]|c[54]$")
```

Or, with base R:

```
grep("^c[45]|c[45]$", colnames(df))
```

The regex is `^c[45]|c[45]$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `c` - a `c`
- `[45]` - `4` or `5`
- `|` - or
- `c[45]` - `c4` or `c5` ...
- `$` - ... at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Try with `sapply`:

```
colnames(df)[sapply(X = colnames(df), FUN = function (X) substr(X, 1, 2) %in% c("c4", "c5") | substr(X, 3, 4) %in% c("c4", "c5"))]
```

With this, you'll have the colnames started or ended by "c4" or "c5".

If you have colnames with length higher than 4 or you want to use somehting different than "c4" or "c5" you could generalize it with:

```
patterns <- c("c4", "c5") #you can change it

colnames(df)[sapply(X = colnames(df), FUN = function (X) substr(X, 1, 2) %in% patterns  | substr(X, nchar(X) - 1, nchar(X)) %in% patterns )]
```

You can even generalize it more, deppend on case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way also. It works even if you have multiple words in a string.

```
str_detect(colnames(df), "(\bc[45])|(c[45]\b)")
```